# What to do with abandoned or poorly looked after packages in the universe repository?

Tags: repository

I have noticed several packages in the `universe` repository which have been untouched for ages even though upstream has released plenty of new versions (one of which hasn't been updated for 4 years and is seriously buggy). I have also noticed some where they refuse to do anything but put the latest version into the next Ubuntu release, they actually refuse to backport in important security updates into the package even when very many users request this of them.

What can be done about such maintainers? Is there a way of reporting them so that they are either forced to get their act together or be replaced by more competent maintainers?

Comment: You are not talking about Xenial I presume as this has version 2.0.2? I see that Trusty holds the older version ....

Comment: @andrew.46: I was, but this seems to be the first time they've updated it in ages. Anyway, my question is more general than just WireShark as there are other packages with either similar issues or more severe issues. I have now updated my question.